# Stochastic process and unit variance

Tags: stochastic-processes

What does it mean when in stochastic process, we say that the process has unit variance? What is its exact definition?

Answer (score 3):

Dunno, maybe that $\mathrm{var}(X_t)=1$ for every $t$.

Comment: This link to Wolfram Mathworld seems to support this answer:
"A standard normal distribution is a normal distribution with zero mean (mu=0) and unit variance (sigma^2=1)" http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StandardNormalDistribution.html

Answer (score 0):

"Did" has posted a guess.  Here's another.  Some processes $\{X_t\}_{t\ge0}$ satisfy $\operatorname{var}(X_t)=ct$ (Poisson processes, Wiener processes, many others).  Possibly it could mean $c=1$.

(But if something like the [Ornstein–Uhlenbeck process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein%E2%80%93Uhlenbeck_process) is being written about, probably "Did"'s guess is right.)